# Cross platform/language library

Tags: cross-platform, cross-language

Im going to be rewriting a library from .net to something that can be used on different platforms (Mac, Linux, Windows, Android). But i am also hoping that it can be used accross languages (c#, python, java). My initial thought was that c++ would be the best option. But ive never done something like this so im not sure. Is there a standard way this kind of thing is done?

Comment: Do you mean to be able to use identical binaries in multiple different languages, as if it were written in that language? The answer would be no.

Comment: There are already .Net runtimes for all the platforms you list. Many languages have implementations that target .Net IL

Comment: @Zymus Not the same binaries, just the same code base. I know that I would need to compile for each platform I am targeting. I'm just trying to avoid being restricted to 1 platform.

Comment: @Caleth I had not considered that the different languages would provide a library for working with .Net. I will see if I can find more information on those.

Answer (score 2):

The "lowest common denominator" language is usually C.  Because so much historical code was written in C, including operating systems, many other languages have the facility to call C functions.

That doesn't necessarily mean you have to write in C.  In C++, functions can be labelled `extern "C"` and are linked as if they were written in C.

Other languages may also have the ability to export functions as if they were written in C.

Comment: And it takes a lot of knowledge to write portable code in C or C++. There must be summaries somewhere on how to do it.

Comment: @Simon B That was my initial thought. Having never written a library with this kind of requirement I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it. I also know that importing C libraries can be a pain. I know it has been for me in the past using .Net

Comment: @FrankHileman The difficulty is also a concern. But I haven't been able to come with a better alternative yet.

Answer (score 0):

One bigger product I know which targets different languages is [AlgLib](http://www.alglib.net). According to their FAQ, they use a programming language named AlgoPascal which is cross-translated to C++, C# or Delphi, and supports also different platforms.

*(Disclaimer: I have no connections or relationships to that company, and I cannot tell you anything about the quality of their software.)*

Unfortunately, the AlgoPascal translator is not publicly available, but at least it shows a way of how such a cross platform/language library can be build. However, I guess this can only be a sensible way if the lib based on such a common source does not need any other platform- or language specific dependencies like some specific UI framework. A math lib like AlgLib is probably well suited for such an approach.